# Disable parent nav links on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

I have a menu in WordPress, where the parent menu item links to a landing page. I'd like it so on mobile devices only this link is disabled. Currently, when clicking on mobile devices the parent items both link to another page AND show dropdown menus, so it's a race...

I tried using media queries and pointer-events: none but it didn't seem to do anything when tested on my phone. And of course, the submenu links have to continue to work.

Thank you!

```
 <div class="mobile-nav"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></div>
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">              
    <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-733"><a href="#">Company</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-224" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-224"><a href="#">Press/News</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-323" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-323"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-405" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-405"><a href="#">Company History</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>           
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using WP, and jQuery is included, why not try that?  Change the 1023 to whatever your breakpoint is for mobile.

```
(function($)({
 $(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 1023){
      $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try that clicking the hamburger to show the menu on mobile devices no longer works. Any idea why?